# can't create plugin with Rails 3.2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i've a problem with rails in latest version. 
I 've create a new app (rails new MyProject) but i don't have script/generate, only have script/rails  and when i type

```
ruby ./script/rails generate plugin my_plugin
"Could not find generator plugin.".
```

Do you have any idea how generate plugin template? 
it's possible to create plugin without this command?

PS: i'm using Rails 3.2.1 with ruby 1.8.7 [universal-darwin11.0]

Comment: there is no plugin generator. `rails g` shows available generators.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The plugin generator has been removed with the release of Rails 3.2.0. See the changelog [here](https://gist.github.com/1648523). Now you can use the following command:

```
rails plugin new my_plugin
```

But be careful because you should run the command outside of the project. It creates a whole plugin structure with its own Gemfile. So, after created the plugin, you can use it in your Rails app adding it to the Gemfile with the path option. Something like:

```
gem 'my_plugin', path: '/path/to/my_plugin'
```

I just read that you're using Ruby 1.8.7. Please consider to upgrade to Ruby 1.9.3. Rails 3.2 is the last version of the framework that supports Ruby 1.8.7.

Comment: thank you, it' working... i hate rubyonrail official websote, documentation "getting started" is out of date...