# Cannon create vendor plugin

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am using Rails 3.2.2

In my project root command: rails generate plugin somename gives me error:

Could not find generator plugin

I can create only gem plugin.

Could somebody give me any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The plugin generator has been removed as of release 3.2 ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9348489/cant-create-plugin-with-rails-3-2)). Try this: `rails plugin new my_plugin`

Comment: Thanks, it generated plugin in app_root/plugin_name, how can my rails application see this plugin?

Comment: That is a much larger topic... the following link is a starting point: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/plugins.html. You may need to ask a few more questions here.

Comment: I followed instruction in http://guides.rubyonrails.org/plugins.html#non-gem-plugins but my app don't see new String method.

Comment: Hmmm... you might want to post another Q regarding that with code & error and seeing if someone can help.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to digest how plugins created internally:
https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/railties/lib/rails/generators/rails/plugin_new/plugin_new_generator.rb  line 170 initialize